# how to loop through a nested list within a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hi I am getting a typerror when I write my code and I cannot figure out why this is the case. if anybody could help it would be much appreciated!

```
latest = ["time", 7]

current_Stock = [["time", "8"], [{"N/A": "N/A", "N/A": "N/A", 
                                  'historical_data': [['sec', 10], 
                                                      ["sec", 5], 
                                                      ["sec", 2], 
                                                      ["sec", 7], 
                                                      ["sec", 9], 
                                                      ["sec", 8]]}]]

i = 0

for x in currentStock[1]['historical_data']:
    if latest[1] == currentStock[1]['historical_data'][i][1]:
        associated_value = currentStock[1]['historical_data'][i][1]

        print(associated_value)
```

Comment: can you add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Your dictionary contains duplicate keys as well ```"N/A"```

Comment: `currentStock[1]` is a `list`, not a `dict`, so trying to index into it with `'historical_data'` will produce a TypeError.  Try using `currentStock[1][0]['historical_data']` instead.

Comment: after `[['sec', 10],` the logic is `"sec", 5],` must be `["sec", 5],` and probably also *current_Stock* must be *currentStock*

Comment: Your data structure is a big mess (beyond the extra and missing `[]`, you don't even have `currentStock` spelled the same.  Try starting from simple statements and building up instead of typing everything and crossing your fingers =)

Comment: @TomKarzes currentStock[1] isn't even defined.... ```current_stock``` is though.

Comment: @EdwinCruz Oh, good point.  I was using the name from the loop rather than the assignment.  Except it's `current_Stock`, not `current_stock`.  It's hard to know what OP is actually running.

Comment: What do you mean by name from the loop? It seems you are not using x in the loop...

Comment: @EdwinCruz The `for` statement uses the name `currentStock`.  That's what I meant.

Comment: Yeah, but why do you have the for loop using ```in``` if you aren't using x?

Comment: @EdwinCruz Yes, that doesn't make much sense either.  By the way, you keep saying "you aren't using x".  I'm not using anything.  It's not my code.

Comment: @TomKarzes Oh my apologies. Thought you were OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
def iterate(lst, pkey= None):
    if isinstance(lst, dict):
        for key in lst:
          iterate(lst[key], key) # call

    elif isinstance(lst, (list, set)):
        for l in lst:
          iterate(l, pkey) # call
    else:
        print(lst) # do something
```

---

```
iterate(current_Stock)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, you defined the list as `current_Stock` and used it as `currentStock`.
- Secondly, You forgot to iterate through the list containing the dictionary.
- Third, you forgot to update the value of `i` at the end of the `for` loop.
  Try this and let me know if you face any issue/error. Here you go:

```
latest = ["time", 7]
currentStock = [["time", "8"], [{"N/A": "N/A", "N/A": "N/A", 'historical_data': [['sec', 10], ["sec", 5], ["sec", 2], ["sec", 7], ["sec", 9], ["sec", 8]]}]]
i = 0
for x in currentStock[1][0]['historical_data']:
    if latest[1] == currentStock[1][0]['historical_data'][i][1]:
        associated_value = currentStock[1][0]['historical_data'][i][1]
        print(associated_value)
    i+=1
```